# Do some preprocessing before starting the pipeline in Apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I need to create an apache beam pipeline using Java SDK that will read data from Google Cloud Storage. The files are pushed by an upstream process and can have invalid files. For example, the file header may not be in the expected format. I would like to move all those invalid files into an error location and my pipeline should read only valid files using TextIO.

I tried to do that via normal java file operation and when tried to run on google data flow using flex template, it gave me timeout error (Timeout in polling result file)

Is there anyway in which I can accomplish the above task?

Answer (score 1):

Flex Template launcher have an embedded time limit to start the job of 12 minutes. Ideally, you should focus your program on creating the actual job pipeline graph.

Can you add such validations as part of the pipeline itself? For example, matching files from `FileIO.match().filepattern`, and using a `DoFn`/`PTransform` that will only emit valid files?

This may give some ideas: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/#accessing-filenames